# undefined behavior with std::labs with unsigned number across multiple platforms

Tags: c++, embedded-linux

I want to find absolute of (a-b), where a, b are 32-Bit unsigned integer. I have used **[std::labs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs)** as shown below. But the operation is behaving differently in different platforms!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    uint32_t x = 0, y = 0, z_u = 0, result_labs = 0, result_abs = 0, result_llabs = 0;
    int32_t z = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        x = rand();
        y = rand();

        z = x - y;
        z_u = x - y;

        result_labs = labs(x - y);   //Problematic Call

        result_abs = std::abs(static_cast<int32_t>(x) - static_cast<int32_t>(y));
        result_llabs = static_cast<uint32_t>(llabs(x - y));

        if ((result_abs != result_labs) || (result_abs != result_llabs))
        {
            printf("[Error] X: %d       Y: %d      z: %d    z_u: %u   \tlabs: %d    - abs: %d    llabs: %d\n", x, y, z, z_u, result_labs, result_abs, result_llabs);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Problem:**

operations on unsigned integer using [std::labs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) is producing different results in different platform's. e.g gcc linux , ghs platforms
How to correctly handle this abs difference computation?

/*Sample Output in VS in Windows PC

```
[Error] X: 41         Y: 18467      z: -18426    z_u: 4294948870          labs: 18426    - abs: 18426    llabs: -18426
[Error] X: 6334       Y: 26500      z: -20166    z_u: 4294947130          labs: 20166    - abs: 20166    llabs: -20166
[Error] X: 11478      Y: 29358      z: -17880    z_u: 4294949416          labs: 17880    - abs: 17880    llabs: -17880
[Error] X: 5705       Y: 28145      z: -22440    z_u: 4294944856          labs: 22440    - abs: 22440    llabs: -22440
[Error] X: 2995       Y: 11942      z: -8947     z_u: 4294958349          labs: 8947     - abs: 8947     llabs: -8947
[Error] X: 4827       Y: 5436       z: -609      z_u: 4294966687          labs: 609      - abs: 609      llabs: -609
```

GHS Output

```
[Error] X: 11188   Y: 27640   z: -16452    z_u: 4294950844  labs: -16452    - abs: 16452    llabs: -16452
[Error] X: 4295    Y: 12490   z: -8195     z_u: 4294959101  labs: -8195     - abs: 8195     llabs: -8195
[Error] X: 5062    Y: 27943   z: -22881    z_u: 4294944415  labs: -22881    - abs: 22881    llabs: -22881
[Error] X: 21352   Y: 32044   z: -10692    z_u: 4294956604  labs: -10692    - abs: 10692    llabs: -10692
[Error] X: 4714    Y: 9737    z: -5023     z_u: 4294962273  labs: -5023     - abs: 5023     llabs: -5023
[Error] X: 17346   Y: 28482   z: -11136    z_u: 4294956160  labs: -11136    - abs: 11136    llabs: -11136
```

Comment: wrong/unexpected results is not necessarily undefined behavior. In your code the calll to `labs` is commented with `// correct output`, so whats wrong with it?

Comment: The correct output is producing wrong output in embedded, similar to the undefined behaviour!

Comment: please include expected and actual output in the question. The output from `labs` you posted looks ok

Comment: `in embedded` What "embeeded"? For each of tested "platforms": what compiler are you using, what platform is that exactly, what compiler options are you using? Your code maybe invalid - you are printing `uint32_t` with `%u`. You are comparing apples and oranges - your function works on unsigned values, `labs` works on a __signed__ `long`. Surely unsigned is going to be some big number. `T` needs to be signed, either you have to convert your values before or after calculation. `uint32_t - uint32_t` is always going to be positive, it wraps around...

Comment: When `x` is less than `y`, `x-y` is a very large unsigned number, since both operands are unsigned.

Comment: The test is broken - live - https://godbolt.org/z/Gc8GTnc6d - clang detects the UB and removes most of the code.  Comment out line 21 `result_abs = abs(x - y);        //Undifined behaviour` to see what happens.  Other compilers many or may not detect the UB but either way the UB in the code invalidates all tests.

Comment: @RichardCritten `clang detects the UB` There is no undefined behavior in the code. The warning states that there is no difference - that's defined behavior.

Comment: `gcc linux , ghs platforms` Could you be more specific? I _guess_ the difference is that `sizeof(long)` on your "linux" has 64-bits, while on your "ghs platform" it has 32-bits, which makes `labs` work differently. Please print `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(long))` on both platforms and check.

Comment: I have tested this code in GHS platform!

Comment: hi Test comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is defined (except may be for the `printf`).

You call the functions with `x - y` argument. Both `x` and `y` are `uint32_t` so the result **is also** `uint32_t`, so it will **never be negative**. Arithmetic operations on unsigned types "wraps around".

`labs` takes `long` argument, so the argument is **converted** to `long` before passing to the function. So `uint32_t` is **converted** to `long`, which is implementation-defined, but basically means that values greater then `LONG_MAX` result in a negative value.

Your `abs` is a template called with `uint32_t` type, because the argument has `uint32_t` type. `uint32_t` will **never** be negative, so `(val >= static_cast<T>(0))` is just always true, and it is an identity function.

`llabs` takes `long long` argument, so the argument is converted to `long long`. `long long` has at least 64-bits, `LLONG_MAX` is at least somewhere around `2^63-1`. Any value of type `uint32_t` is representable with `long long`. `uint32_t` is never negative, converting to `long long` does not change the value, so `llabs` just receives a positive value, so `llabs` it just does nothing and returns the original value.

Your `printf` calls may be invalid - `%u` is for printing `unsigned int`, not `uint32_t`. Use `PRIu32` from `inttypes.h`, or use C++:

```
#include <cinttypes>
int main() {
   uint32_t val;
   printf("%"PRIu32"\n", val);
   // or, for example explicit C-style cast:
   printf("%u\n", (unsigned)val);
}
```

> What is the correct way to implement the std::labs in c++?

```
long labs(long x) {
   return x < 0 ? -x : x;
}
```

is just enough. Note that the types are *explicitly* long.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and detailed answer! The reason for the %u in printf is to replicate the usage in the code as uint32_t! "Both x and y are uint32_t so the result is also uint32_t, so it will never be negative. Arithmetic operations on unsigned types "wraps around"" I never thought about this!

Comment: `So uint32_t is converted to long, which is implementation-defined` It's standard defined since C++20.

Comment: just to confirm what is the correct way of finding abs(x-y)?

Comment: You have to define "correct" then. Your code works correctly as it is - `x-y` is a positive value, and your function `abs(x-y)` returns a positive value - looks correct to me. You seem to want to implement `subtract_then_abs(x, y)`. That could be just `llabs((long long)x - (loing long)y)`, which would work "correctly" for `uint32_t` variables and would return a `long long` type, which can represent all the range of  `< -UINT32_t , UINT32_MAX >` values.